# jQuery addclass and remove class not updating properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint ASPMenu in a MasterPage, I;m trying to change the selected style class using jQuery. Basically when user click a menu item it will cause postback so that the page will be directed to the clicked menu url. When the user clicked on a menu item I put the url in the cookie. Then when the page load I'll set the style for the selected menu.  Here are my code so far

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
LinkClicked();  
FireMe();   
});
function FireMe()
{
    var val = $.cookie('sabValue');

    if(val !== null)
    {   
        $(".s4-tn a").each(function(){          
            $(this).removeClass("selected").closest("li").removeClass("selected"); 
        });
        $(".s4-tn a[href='"+val+"']").addClass("selected").closest("li").addClass("selected");          
    }      
}

function LinkClicked(){
    $(".s4-tn a").click(function() {
        var sabValue = $(this).attr("href");
        $.cookie('sabValue',sabValue );
    });         
}
```

My problem is, after the page load (after the user clicked a menu) the changes does not take place. I have to clicked the menu item again so that the selected style is applied.

This is the ASPMenu declaration

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
  ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
  Runat="server"
  EnableViewState="false"
  DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
  AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
  UseSimpleRendering="true"
  UseSeparateCss="false"
  Orientation="Horizontal"
  StaticDisplayLevels="2"
  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
  SkipLinkText=""
  CssClass="s4-tn"/>
```

Why is this happening.
Appreciate any helps.
Thanks

Comment: Please post your generated HTML and JS code to jsfiddle.net .
By the way $(".s4-tn a").each(function()... is not the best way to do that. You can simply write $('.selected', $('.s4-tn') ).removeClass('selected');

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue trying to put together a menu.  This is the code I ended up using.  I had to provide a path to the cookie so it was available via every page.  I also had to remove the cookie each time because I was still getting the duplicate cookie on one of my menu items.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").click(function () {
        $.cookie('selectedPage', null);
        var selectedPage = $(this).attr("id");
        $.cookie('selectedPage', selectedPage, { path: '/' });

        RemoveClass();
    });

    AddClass();
});

function RemoveClass() {
    $("#menu li").each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
}

function AddClass() {
    var selectedPage = $.cookie('selectedPage');

    if (selectedPage !== null) {
        $("#menu li[id='" + selectedPage + "']").addClass("selected");
    }
}
```

My menu looks like this...

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="mm-one"><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
    <li id="mm-two"><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
    <li id="mm-three"><a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
    <li id="mm-four"><a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling FireMe() from inside LinkClicked? :

```
function LinkClicked(){
    $(".s4-tn a").click(function() {
        var sabValue = $(this).attr("href");
        $.cookie('sabValue',sabValue );

        FireMe(); //you could pass a value here, too
    });         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, when user clicked a menu the user will be directed to the clicked page. So when that page load I want to assign the selected class to the clicked menu item. If I assign the selected class here, it will be lost. That's why I'm using cookie, to hold the clicked href value so that I can find it later and assign the selected class. Do you have any other ideas.Thanks

Comment: You can still set from cookie; but the event needs to fire the function, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your click handler to make the class change. Your fireMe(0 has already been fired on page load. You could call Fireme() inside handler but is more efficient just to add the class to "this"

```
function LinkClicked(){
    $(".s4-tn a").click(function() {
        var sabValue = $(this).attr("href");
        $.cookie('sabValue',sabValue );
        $(".s4-tn a.selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, when user clicked a menu the user will be directed to the clicked page. So when that page load I want to assign the selected class to the clicked menu item. If I assign the selected class here, it will be lost. That's why I'm using cookie, to hold the clicked href value so that I can find it later and assign the selected class. Do you have any other ideas.Thanks

Comment: you could log the values to console so you can compare first load and second click and look for differences